# Show that $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}2^{2k} = 5^n$ $\forall n \in\mathbb{N}$

Tags: combinatorics

I want to show that

> $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}2^{2k} = 5^n$ $\forall n \in\mathbb{N}$

Im trying to convert the sum into some sort of a combinatorial question, But I can't seem to grasp why it adds into $5^n$. I know that (for e.g) $5^n$ indicates how many words of length $n$ you can make out of an alphabet of 5.

Any hint, clue?

Comment: Do you want a combinatorial proof or just any proof? Newton's just enough here.

Comment: Observe that $2^{2k}=4^k1^{n-k}$.

Comment: @BillO'Haran A combinatorical proof. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, as you thought it boils down to building words of length $n$ with an alphabet of length 5.

To do that, you can choose one letter in your alphabet, select the number of times $k$ it will not appear in your word (that's the sum: it won't appear once OR twice OR ... and so on) and select the places where you will not put this letter (that's the binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{k}$). Then you have to fill in the remaining letters with the letters left in your alphabet ($4^{k}$ possibilities).

In the end, constructing words this way indeed yields all the words of length $n$ with that alphabet of length 5 exactly once.

Comment: Amazing. thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is just the binomial expansion of $(1+2^{2})^{n}$.

Comment: That's a great observation. thanks alot!